# How can I correct my code to create the file to save weights in python?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I want to create a .h5 file to store my weights into it. I will use these weights in validation and testing.
This is my code. I don't understand, is my path incorrect or there is something else.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
hf = h5py.File(r"E:\weights.h5", 'w')
```

I am not getting any error. But I can't see the file. When I open the path, there is no .h5 file. Please help
I just want to create the file. Don't want to save any dummy data in it.

Comment: I have created this [repl](https://repl.it/@Glusk/IcyWornVariety) project and your code creates a file without any issues.

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me today too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're passing the arguments wrong. I don't have experience with h5py, however according to the docs, the line should look like this:

```
hf = h5py.File("E:\weights.h5", 'a')
```

The first argument passed is the file itself, whereas the second one is the mode you'd like to open the file in.
https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html

I hope this works

Comment: I corrected it but still, file is not creating. What should I do?